# How do I programmatically retrieve the control associated with a given table field?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have an Access database in which every table/view is linked back to a SQL Server object. The tables have been heavily customized. Many of the fields are comboboxes with simple rowsources: `SELECT field1, field2, blahBlah FROM blahTable`

We want to delete a bunch of tables, and I'd like to make sure that none of the tables are referenced in these field subqueries. It seems like I should be able to write some code to iterate through every table, and every field of every table, and then print the rowsource if one exists.

I can write code to access all the table fields. I can write code to access the row source of a control. But I cannot figure out how to get the control associated with a given field, or if this is even the right approach. Everything I see online is either how to manually find this info, or assumes that the control's parent is a form, not a field or table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Properties` collection for an Access lookup field includes *RowSourceType* and *RowSource*.

*RowSourceType* will tell you whether the source is a query or a value list.  Then for a query, *RowSource* will show you the SQL.

A complication here is that those two properties only exist for lookup fields.  Attempting to access them for a different field type will trigger error # 3270, *"Property not found."*  You could deal with that by adding an error handler which ignores error # 3270.  Or you could check whether the property exists and only ask for its value when it does exist.

It should be easy to inspect each field of your tables and print the *RowSource* for lookup fields:

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef

Set db = CurrentDb
For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*" Or tdf.Name Like "~*") Then
        For Each fld In tdf.Fields
            If HasProperty(fld, "RowSource") Then
                Debug.Print tdf.Name; "."; fld.Name; " Rowsource: " & vbCrLf, _
                    fld.Properties("RowSource").Value
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

The code above relies on Allen Browne's [HasProperty](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-73.html#HasProperty) function:

```vb
Public Function HasProperty(obj As Object, strPropName As String) As Boolean
    'Purpose:   Return true if the object has the property.
    Dim varDummy As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    varDummy = obj.Properties(strPropName)
    HasProperty = (Err.Number = 0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use these features, but I am sure that what you are looking for is in the DAO.Properties collection for the field. Sample code:

```
Public Sub ShowDAOProperties(ByVal rProperties As DAO.Properties)

    Dim rPrp As DAO.Property
    Dim vName As Variant
    Dim vValue As Variant
    Dim vType As Variant

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each rPrp In rProperties
        With rPrp
            vName = .Name
            vType = .Type
            vValue = .Value
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                Debug.Print vName, vValue, vType
            Else
                Debug.Print "====>"; Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vName
                Err.Clear
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

For a field, call using:

`ShowDAOProperties CurrentDb.TableDefs("table").Fields("field").Properties`

You should be able to pick out the properties you are interested in from the list that is generated.

Comment: Thanks for the proc. I suggest adjusting it slightly, since I needed to refer to another person's answer to get the info I was looking for.

Since I am only interested in the SQL queries, I removed the For/Each loop, and set rPrp = rProperties("RowSource"). This returns the info I need. 

As an aside, I've been using VBA for over ten years, and I didn't know you could use commas to print multiple variables on one line with Debug.Print. So thanks for that also.

Comment: You're welcome. Please modify the code any way you like.